# Find the shortest distance between A and B in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, shortest-path

That's the the best and fastest solution for this problem:

find the shortest distance between A and B, with A and B is in an array there is list of value in array such as [4, 8, 9, 10, 100], we need to find out the smallest gap between two value in that array. if it is negative then use the absolute one.

Comment: What does 'best' mean? is seems different from 'fastest' by the way you worded your question.

Comment: @kevin Between any two values or any two consecutive values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Sort the given array
- Find the low­est dif­fer­ence for a pair of ele­ments in the sorted array
- Find all the pairs with the low­est difference

```
function closetPairs (arr) {
    let result = []; 
    let minDiff = Number.MAX_VALUE;

    arr.sort((a, b) => { 
        return a - b;
    });

    // find the lowest difference for a pair of elements in the sorted array
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        let currDiff = arr[i + 1] - arr[i];
        if (currDiff < minDiff) {
            minDiff = currDiff;
        }
    }

    // find all the pairs with lowest differnece
        for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
            let sortedEleDiff = arr[j + 1] - arr[j];
            if (minDiff == sortedEleDiff) {
                result.push(arr[j + 1], arr[j]);
            }
        }

        return result.sort((a, b) => { 
            return a - b;
        });

    }

    let inputArr = [4, 8, 9, 10, 100];

    console.log(closetPairs(inputArr)); // [ 8, 9, 9, 10 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the array first, you can then just find the smallest absolute value difference between any two neighboring elements.

```js
let data = [4,8,9,10,100];

function findSmallDelta(data) {

  data.sort();
  let minDelta = -1;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
      let delta = Math.abs(data[i] - data[i+1]);
      if (minDelta === -1 || delta < minDelta) {
          minDelta = delta;
      }
  }
  return minDelta;
}

console.log(findSmallDelta(data));
```

If you don't want to affect the source array, you can make a copy of the source array before sorting.  It seems likely that sorting the array and then just testing the delta between neighboring elements is likely faster than comparing all possible deltas.

Comment: @kevin - I'm just curious why you chose the answer you did as the accept answer since it appears to be more complicated than this one.